# Java Runtime Environment 1.4.2 Installation

Tags: java, oracle, jre, jvm

I´ve got HP Proliant dl380 g3 and I can´t use few things from the "iLO(integrated lights-out)" because this tool needs the Java Runtime Environment 1.4.2 to run in my browser

HP does not support this Old server so I tried to install it by myself:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase14-419411.html#j2sdk-1.4.2_30-sol-JPR

I downloaded the j2re-1_4_2_19-linux-i586.bin and executed it in the terminal and this is the result:

```
Do you agree to the above license terms? [yes or no] 
yes
Unpacking...
Checksumming...
0
0
Extracting...
./j2re-1_4_2_19-linux-i586.bin: 383: ./j2re-1_4_2_19-linux-i586.bin: ./install.sfx.5638: not found
Done.
```

Any idea of what should I do?

Thanks for your Time!

Comment: I'm confused...you installed it, what seems to be the problem here? What is wrong? If you are getting an error, what error?

Comment: the things is that when I go and try to use the tool I mentioned before, it keeps telling I should install JVM 1.4.2.  I open the installation file to see what happened and even thou it say "Done", "./install.sfx.5638" it´s just the beginning. It just quit the installation and says "I don´t find this file.... done".

Answer (score 1):

If you need an elder version of Sun Java (bought by Oracle), you need to download it from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html, unpack it yourself, and update your $PATH to point to it.  Possibly also your $JAVA_HOME for some tooling.

[The oficial Installation Notes for Linux](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/install-linux-140719.html)

1. Make sure that execute permissions are set Run this command:

   chmod    +x j2re-1_4_2_-linux-i586.bin
2. Run the self-extracting binary.

   Execute the downloaded file, prepended by the path to it. For
   example, if the file is in the current directory, prepend it with "
   ./" (necessary if " ." is not in the PATH environment variable):

   ./j2re-1_4_2_-linux-i586.bin

> Note about System Preferences: By default, the installation script
>   configures the system such that the backing store for system
>   preferences is created inside the Java 2 Runtime Environment's
>   installation directory. If the J2RE is installed on a network-mounted
>   drive, it and the system preferences can be exported for sharing with
>   Java runtime environments on other machines. As an alternative, root
>   users can use the -localinstall option when running the installation
>   script, as in this example:
>
> j2re-1_4_2_-linux-i586.bin -localinstall This option causes
>   the system preferences to be stored in the /etc directory from which
>   they can be shared only by VMs running on the local machine. You must
>   be root user for the -localinstall option to work.

Answer (score 0):

lets try to install Full JDK(Java Development kit) JRE(Java Run-Time Environment) (included) to avoid problems.
type these in terminal if your system is Debian:
the first thing ,we need to add repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

do an update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and finally installing jdk with jre

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

to verify that you installed java Successfully (optional)

```
 java -version
```

as shown there [how to install Java in Linux Deb](http://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-8-jdk-8-ubuntu-via-ppa/)

Comment: OP needs 1.4.2 and not 8.